# Sass mixin doesn't work in identical conditions

Tags: html, sass, mixins, scss-mixins

I have found a mixin that worked very well when I initially used  it but any subsequent use simply doesn't work, and I'm **really** failing to see what I am doing wrong.
Here's a [Codepen](https://codepen.io/robcsaszar/pen/JjRNoBP) I made with snippets of what works and what doesn't.

The `c-notification__state` is the one that needs to be modified based on state and it doesn't stick, while `c-link__link` works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution, albeit I do not know if it is best-practice, but it now does what it's supposed to. Adding the following right after the `@at-root` fixed it:

```
  &--#{$modifier} {
    @content;
  }
```

I'll leave the Codepen "broken" in case someone would like to mention that I might have done something wrong.